# How can I put integer as an argument in jq?

Tags: json, jq, jsawk

I have been trying to use jq to parse a json file returned from the aws cli, but I'm stuck with the problem of referencing an array using the index number. I need to do this because I want to export a text file describing the security groups in a specific format, including all the inbound and outbound rules.

```
for (( i=1; i<=groupCount; i++ )) ; 
do
    echo $i
    echo $(echo "$input" | jq --arg i $i '.SecurityGroups[$i]')
done
```

This returns an error:

```
1
jq: error (at <stdin>:189): Cannot index array with string "1"

2
jq: error (at <stdin>:189): Cannot index array with string "2"

3
jq: error (at <stdin>:189): Cannot index array with string "3"
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You would either have to use the command line arg `--argjson` or `fromjson` filter to convert the argument to a number.  Arrays are may only be indexed by ints and using `--arg` keeps the input as a string.

```
$ jq --argjson i "$i" '.SecurityGroups[$i]'
$ jq --arg i "$i" '.SecurityGroups[$i|fromjson]'
```

Comment: Note that you could also use `tonumber` instead of `fromjson`.

Comment: you're a legend!