# Adding field to json with jq, forcing type

Tags: json, jq

I need to add a float field to a json, I'm doing somthing like :

```
echo '{"field":' '"value"}' | jq --arg id 21841453190106 --arg price 1.2 '.+ {$price}'
```

getting:

```
{
  "field": "value",
  "price": "1.2"
}
```

I'd like to have:

```
{
  "field": "value",
  "price": 1.2
}
```

thanks

**EDIT**: thanks to 0stone0 :

```
echo '{"field":' '"value"}' | jq --arg id 21841453190106 --argjson price 1 '.+ {$price}'
```

gives:

```
{
  "field": "value",
  "price": 1
}
```

any way to have

```
{
  "field": "value",
  "price": 1.0
}
```

?

Comment: use `--argjson`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I put integer as an argument in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752499/how-can-i-put-integer-as-an-argument-in-jq)

Comment: wow, that was fast!
Thanks, any way to have ".0",too ?

echo '{"field":' '"value"}' | jq --argjson id 21841453190106 --argjson price 1 '.+ {$price}'
{
  "field": "value",
  "price": 1
}

"price":1.0

Comment: Please see [this git issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1301), `1.0` is the same as `1` in number-land. If you provide eg `1.2` to `argjson` it wil keep the decimal places.

Comment: once again, thanks. I see the point of 1.0 and 1 being the same, I would have needed this on the json receiver end, but I'll find other means to work this out.
Thanks!